# How to group by more than one key and sum its values in an array of objects, using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

In the array below, I want to group by `item` and `reason`, then calculate the total `quantity`:

```js
item_movements = [
  {
    item: "Apple",
    reason: 1,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    item: "Banana",
    reason: 2,
    quantity: 10
  },
  {
    item: "Apple",
    reason: 1,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    item: "Banana",
    reason: 1,
    quantity: 8
  },
  {
    item: "Apple",
    reason: 2,
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    item: "Banana",
    reason: 1,
    quantity: 8
  }
];
```

The result I am trying to achieve is this:

```js
item_totals = [
  {
    item: "Apple",
    1: 10,
    2: 3
  },
  {
    item: "Banana",
    1: 16,
    2: 10
  }
];
```

I was able to group by `item` using Loadash like so:

```js
({
  itemMovementbyItem() {
    var result = _(this.item_movements)
      .groupBy(x => x.item)
      .map((value, key) => ({
        item: key,
        item_movements: value
      }))
      .value()

    return result
  }
})
```

But I am having problems to group a second time by `reason`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sum the properies directly after grouping by `'item'`.

```js
function itemMovementbyItem(array) {
    return _(array)
        .groupBy('item')
        .map(group => ({
            item: group[0].item,
            1: _.sumBy(group, o => o.reason === 1 ? o.quantity : 0),
            2: _.sumBy(group, o => o.reason === 2 ? o.quantity : 0)
        }))
        .value();
}

var item_movements = [{ item: "Apple", reason: 1, quantity: 5 }, { item: "Banana", reason: 2, quantity: 10 }, { item: "Apple", reason: 1, quantity: 5 }, { item: "Banana", reason: 1, quantity: 8 }, { item: "Apple", reason: 2, quantity: 3 }, { item: "Banana", reason: 1, quantity: 8 }];

console.log(itemMovementbyItem(item_movements));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` to build one object with keys as item. Get `Object.values` from object.

```js
const item_movements = [
  {
    item: "Apple",
    reason: 1,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    item: "Banana",
    reason: 2,
    quantity: 10
  },
  {
    item: "Apple",
    reason: 1,
    quantity: 5
  },
  {
    item: "Banana",
    reason: 1,
    quantity: 8
  },
  {
    item: "Apple",
    reason: 2,
    quantity: 3
  },
  {
    item: "Banana",
    reason: 1,
    quantity: 8
  }
];

const all = item_movements.reduce((acc, { item, reason, quantity }) => {
  acc[item] =
    item in acc
      ? {
          ...acc[item],
          [reason]: (acc[item][reason] || 0) + quantity
        }
      : { item, [reason]: quantity };
  return acc;
}, {});

const item_totals = Object.values(all);

console.log(item_totals);
```

Comment: @Catmal, My bad. Just fixed the bug and updated the answer. it should be working now.